# Estimate 3D Line from Image projections with known Camera Pose and Calibration

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, geometry

I know the principle of triangulation for 3D Point estimation from images.
However, how would you solve the following problem, I have images from a Line in 3D space with known Camera position and also known calibration. But since I don't know how much/which segment of the Line is seen in eag image, I am not sure how to form an equation for the Line estimation. See image (I have more than 2 images available, in all images most part of the Line visible should be the same, but not exact the same):

[image: Setup, I got more than two poses]

I am thinking of spanning a plane from the Camera through the line in the image and intersecting all Planes spanned from each perspective to get an estimate of the Line?
However, I don't really know if that's possible or how I could do this.

Thanks for any help.
Cheers

Comment: your approach in the last paragraph appears sound to me. intersecting planes, yes. I'm not that practiced in this stuff, so I'd approach this "intuitively". per view per line, I'd calculate two viewing rays (pick points from the line in the picture) and from those two vectors figure a plane normal (cross product) and the camera is part of the plane so there's the supporting point. the rest is looking up how all that linear algebra works and building the equations and solving them.

Comment: perhaps get a hold of the "multiple view geometry" book. maybe matrices like the essential or the fundamental matrix can be involved gainfully.

Comment: good Point! Did not actually think about two rays and span the plane there. I just thought about how to span the plane directly, thanks!

Comment: there is *probably* some math to turn the line into a plane but eh, something for later, when everything works, right? the line is already one vector. it lies on the image plane. another vector is any vector from the camera's origin through the line.

Answer (score 1):

Afraid other answers and comments have it backwards, pun intended.

Backprojecting ("triangulating") image lines into 3D space and then trying to fit them together with some ad-hoc heuristics may be good for an initial approximation.

However, to refine this approximation, you should then assume that a 3D line exists with unknown parameters (a point and a unit vector), plus additional scalar parameters identifying the initial and final points along the line of the segments you observe.  Using the projection equations, you then set up an optimization problem whose goal is to find the set of parameters that minimize the projection errors of the 3D line with those parameters onto the images. This is essentially bundle adjustment, but expressed in the language of your problem, and in fact you can use any good software package for bundle adjustment (hint: Ceres) to solve it. The initial approximation computed with some ad-hoc heuristic will be used as the starting point of the bundle adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

Plane can be defined with one point and direction.
If bot cameras are calibrated and have known position then ...
Make two planes, first from first camera, using eye and projected line second plane  at the same way.
Line from screen you can easily convert to line in space because you have camera position.
What is left to intersect those two planes.

Comment: hey, yeah thats what I am thinking about. But how do I create a Plane in world space from the camera position and the projected line?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253635/equation-of-a-plane-given-point-and-line